# Extraer grupos con regex

Tags: python, regex

Tengo la siguiente lista:

```
['carnes-carnero', 'carnes-ave', 'carnes-ternera', 'carnes-anade', 'carnes-cabrito', 'carnes-capon', 'carnes-caracol', 'carnes-conejo', 'carnes-cerdo', 'carnes-varios', 'carnes-gallina', 'carnes-liebre', 'carnes-grulla', 'carnes-lechon', 'carnes-pollo', 'carnes-paloma', 'carnes-perdiz', 'carnes-pichon', 'carnes-venado', 'carnes-embutidos']
```

Quiero extraer las palabras que van después del guión. Por ejemplo, carnes-carnero, debería extraer carnero.

He realizado lo siguiente:

```
import re
pattern = re.compile(r'-(\w+)')

if carns:
    result = [carn.group(1) for carn in carns if re.match(pattern,carn)]

print(result)
```

Sin embargo, obtengo una lista vacía y no soy capaz de ver el error.

Gracias

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tienes un par de problemas en tu enfoque.

- Primero, la expresión regular que usas no es correcta, ya que cuando usas `re.match()` se espera que la expresión regular encaje *completamente* con la cadena. Tu expresión regular viene a decir "una palabra con un - delante", pero las cadenas que le pasas no tienen esa estructura, sino que serían "una palabra, un guión, una palabra". Por eso `match()` no encaja con ninguna y obtienes una lista vacía.
- Segundo, si alguna encajara aún así tendrías un error porque en caso de que encajen evalúas `carn.group(1)` y eso te dará un error puesto que `carn` es la cadena que estás procesando (por ejemplo `'carnes-carnero'`, y no el resultado de `re.match()`.

### Soluciones

El primer problema se puede resolver de dos formas:

- Cambia la expresión regular por `r"\w+-(\w+)"` y entonces `re.match()` ya encajará, pues ahora sí estamos especificando "una palabra, un guión, una palabra", pero al poner sólo la segunda entre paréntesis sólo capturamos la segunda.
- Usa `re.search()` en lugar de `re.match()`. Esta opción permite la búsqueda de la expresión regular *en cualquier lugar de la cadena*. Por tanto en este caso no necesitas cambiar la expresión regular que puede seguir siendo `r"-(\w+)"`

El segundo problema tiene solución más fea, especialmente si usas Python <= 3.7. No queda más remedio que repetir el matching así:

```
result = [re.search(pattern, carn).group(1) for carn in carns 
          if re.search(pattern,carn)]
```

Esta repetición además de fea es un poco ineficiente, pues estás haciendo dos veces la búsqueda, una para decidir si el elemento formará parte del resultado y otra para extraer el grupo hallado.

Una forma de evitar esa repetición es prescindir de la comprensión de listas y hacerlo en un bucle:

```
result = []
for carn in carns:
   r = re.search(pattern, carn)
   if r:
      result.append(r.group(1))
```

Otra forma, si tienes Python >= 3.8, es usar su nuevo operador `:=` (llamado *walrus* porque parece una morsa si lo miras de lado). Este operador permite hacer una asignación en lugares donde Python esperaría una expresión, como por ejemplo en un `if`. Así la comprensión quedaría:

```
result = [r.group(1) for carn in carns if (r:=re.search(pattern,carn))]
```

En el `if` del final usamos `r:=` para asignar a `r` el resultado del `re.search()` y en la expresión al inicio de la comprensión podemos usar `r.group()`

## Ampliación

Dicho todo lo anterior, yo no usaría expresiones regulares para este problema tan simple. Lo que quieres es mirar si hay un guión en la palabra y en ese caso dividir por él para quedarte con la del final, por lo que bastaría:

```
result = [ carn.split("-")[-1] for carn in carns if "-" in carn ]
```